# Kafka, streams applications runs for a few days then "WARN broker may not be available"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are running around 30 kafka-streams applications on kubernetes. They usually run fine for a few days but after some random time some of the applications enter a state

```
2021-11-05 09:44:01,183 [1-producer] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient     - [Producer clientId=appId-cd74cfbc-4c6a-49b4-823d-ac21beae2c27-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 (********) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2021-11-05 09:44:01,183 [amThread-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient     - [Consumer clientId=appId-cd74cfbc-4c6a-49b4-823d-ac21beae2c27-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=groupId] Connection to node -2 (******) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

2021-11-05 09:44:01,183 [amThread-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient     - [Consumer clientId=appId-cd74cfbc-4c6a-49b4-823d-ac21beae2c27-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=groupId] Bootstrap broker ****** (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected

2021-11-05 09:44:01,183 [1-producer] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient     - [Producer clientId=cd74cfbc-4c6a-49b4-823d-ac21beae2c27-StreamThread-1-producer] Bootstrap broker ****** (id: -1 rack: null)
```

These warnings will continue being spammed out in the log for around every 2 minutes and last time it kept going on for 2 days until we realized some apps had stopped processing (I know we are working on setting up some monitoring). In the end the applications wont recover until manually restarted, and since the applications never throw an error it never gets propagated to the liveness probe.

Does anyone know if there are some configs or so that we can add to the kafka-streams library so that the applications stops spamming warnings after a certain amount of times and just throws an error so we can fail and automatically restart?

Also worth mentioning is that the brokers are up and running and other streams applications are up and processing against the same kafka-cluster.

Comment: You can configure log4j to reduce log output, not Kafka Streams

Comment: The issue is not the amount of logging we receive. The issues is that the brokers are up, other applications communicate with kafka so on the broker side everything works. But somehow some applications after a while end up in this state and never recovers until manually restarted and we cant figure out why.

I have figured out that kubernetes restarted the applications once from checking in kibana, but then they request metadata and fail to get metadata and end up here in this loop.

Comment: having the same problem... did you find a way to solve it ?